# Move and Rotate GMSMarker smoothly along last updated GPS coordinates Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, catransaction

I'm using **GMSMapView**. So I added custom **GMSMarker** and set the image(Ex. Bike image) and animating that marker when user starts moving and changing the angle of the marker in locationManager .

Currently I'm just updating position attribute of GMSMarker. **But** it gives the GMSMarker   jump effect. **Instead of this** I want to **move and rotate** the GMSMarker **smoothly/properly** into the GMSMapView.

How can i achieve this in Swift? Thanks.

```
   (void)updateLocationoordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinates
    { 
     if (marker == nil) {
      marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinates];
      marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE];
      marker.map = mapView;
    } else{
     marker.position = coordinates; 
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem and tried many ways. At last I've came up with a solution - to take angle between previous location point and present location point and I've used an UIImageView instead of GMSMarker.

```
//in location update method
CGPoint anglepoint = [myMapView.projection pointForCoordinate:currLocation.coordinate];
CGFloat angle = [self getAngle:anglepoint];
if(!isnan(angle)){
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8f];
     sampleImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
     [sampleImgView setCenter:[myMapView.projection pointForCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currLocation.coordinate.latitude, currLocation.coordinate.longitude)]];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
     prevCurrLocation = currLocation;
}


-(CGFloat) getAngle: (CGPoint) touchedPoints
{
    CGPoint previousLocationPoint = [myMapView.projection pointForCoordinate:prevCurrLocation.coordinate];

    CGFloat x1 = previousLocationPoint.x;
    CGFloat y1 = previousLocationPoint.y;

    CGFloat x2 = touchedPoints.x;
    CGFloat y2 = touchedPoints.y;

    CGFloat x3 = x1;
    CGFloat y3 = y2;

    CGFloat oppSide = sqrtf(((x2-x3)*(x2-x3)) + ((y2-y3)*(y2-y3)));
    CGFloat adjSide = sqrtf(((x1-x3)*(x1-x3)) + ((y1-y3)*(y1-y3)));

    CGFloat angle = atanf(oppSide/adjSide);
    // Quadrant Identifiaction
    if(x2 < previousLocationPoint.x)
    {
        angle = 0-angle;
    }


    if(y2 > previousLocationPoint.y)
    {
        angle = M_PI/2 + (M_PI/2 -angle);
    }
    return angle;
}
```

Use this for animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
sampleImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[sampleImgView setCenter:[myMapView.projection pointForCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currLocation.coordinate.latitude, currLocation.coordinate.longitude)]];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here is the sample Imageview:

```
sampleImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
sampleImgView.center = myMapView.center;
sampleImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 25, 50);
sampleImgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myMapView addSubview:sampleImgView];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I want to roate the direction of the image then how?Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Satish, Thanks! Could you please share the source code. So it will be helpful to understand and implement!

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Please let me know, if you need specific info.

Comment: Please help! As I asked before! Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you clear with creating GMSMapView and GMS markers?

Comment: Yes! Each and every 3 seconds I am calling an API. Now I want to move and rotate the marker.but its jumping. Please help me in swift.

Comment: I've worked in many ways with GMSMarker but it didn't worked for me in case of rotation. So, i took an ImageView and its working fine.

Comment: Great! Can you please share the codebase.Swift is preferred most!

Comment: Only that particular Viewcontroller. If yes, I will share my mail id!

Comment: sure, but I've worked in Objective-c. Don't worry, there might not be much changes to do to work in swift.

Comment: saved my day brother.. I needed to get the direction for arrow heads.. very helpfull. Thanks a lot +1

Comment: @AhsanEbrahim.. I did it in very easy and simple way.

Comment: @Captain how did you do it ?

Comment: @Captain how did you do it ?

Comment: @Captain : can you share the code snippet in swift3?

Comment: Hello can you share the code for Objective-C for same issue to rorate the GMSMarker Pls?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi @SatishA...can u share the code base of view controller here?